# How to print escaped HTML characters in Oracle XML Publisher

Tags: xml, oracle, xml-publisher, oracle-xml-publisher, oracle-bi

I am using Oracle's [XML Publisher](http://www.erpschools.com/articles/xml-publisher) (based on Oracle XML Parser 10.1.0.5.0) to generate reports from my db using an .RTF template.

In my front end the user enters some values in a CK Editor like the following image:

[image]

In the database the values are saved correctly as shown below:

[image]

When I print the report in PDF format using XML Publisher I get the escaped HTML characters like this:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this and print the normal characters instead of the escaped ones?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Maybe you need [this plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/entities).

Comment: I would think the end goal should be storing it unencoded?

Comment: Are you able to resolve this issue? As I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with Oracle 11g you are able to use the PL/SQL package UTL_I18N.

> UTL_I18N is a set of services that provides additional globalization functionality for applications.

One of the relevant methods in this context is "UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE":

```sql
SELECT UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE('ABC &lt; &#38; &#34;') FROM DUAL;
```

With this you will get an output like: `ABC < & "`

Here are some more information provided by Oracle: 
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_i18n.htm#ARPLS71170